# AWS SQS message push taking 50 secs

Tags: httpclient, aws-sdk, amazon-sqs

For some of the requests, sqsClient send message taking 50+ seconds to push message in SQS queue.
How to pass CLientConfiguration so that timeout happens quickly and accordingly retry happens.
Tried all possible solutions to reduce this timeout of 50 secs but nothing is working.

LOGS:-

```
2023-06-23 13:30:30.873 [] [] [SQSQueueBufferWorkerThread-16] [] [] [] [] DEBUG com.amazonaws.request.executeOneRequest(1288) - Sending Request: POST https://sqs.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com /444121746292/PROD_OA_COMMUNICATION_H
2023-06-23 13:30:30.874 [] [] [SQSQueueBufferWorkerThread-16] [] [] [] [] DEBUG c.a.auth.AWS4Signer.debug(33) - AWS4 Canonical Request: '"POST
/444121746292/PROD_OA_COMMUNICATION_H

amz-sdk-invocation-id:e7a34898-7848-0029-5fd0-a284535470da
amz-sdk-request:ttl=20230623T080120Z;**attempt**=1;max=4
amz-sdk-retry:0/0/500
host:sqs.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com
user-agent:aws-sdk-java/1.12.490 Linux/5.10.165-143.735.amzn2.x86_64 OpenJDK_64-Bit_Server_VM/17.0.7+7-alpine-r1 java/17.0.7 vendor/Alpine cfg/retry-mode/legacy AmazonSQSBufferedAsyncClient/1.12.490
x-amz-date:20230623T080030Z
x-amz-security-token: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

amz-sdk-invocation-id;amz-sdk-request;amz-sdk-retry;host;user-agent;x-amz-date;x-amz-security-token
fbcd61f597391a4e7e0a9eb1a917624d698d4fc3fd154d30e1b29a2242dbb9a1"
2023-06-23 13:30:30.874 [] [] [SQSQueueBufferWorkerThread-16] [] [] [] [] DEBUG c.a.auth.AWS4Signer.debug(33) - AWS4 String to Sign: '"AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
20230623T080030Z

2023-06-23 13:30:30.874 [] [] [SQSQueueBufferWorkerThread-16] [] [] [] [] DEBUG c.a.auth.AWS4Signer.debug(33) - AWS4 String to Sign: '"AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
20230623T080030Z
20230623/ap-south-1/sqs/aws4_request
3971c6f53f806d34ef5fef6e85e6306a3bb22ae0fcff46ffafd7b5830770b04e"


2023-06-23 13:31:20.924 [] [] [SQSQueueBufferWorkerThread-16] [] [] [] [] DEBUG c.a.internal.SdkSSLSocket.shutdownOutput(76) - shutting down output of sqs.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/15.207.13.23:443
2023-06-23 13:31:20.924 [] [] [SQSQueueBufferWorkerThread-16] [] [] [] [] DEBUG c.a.internal.SdkSSLSocket.shutdownInput(69) - shutting down input of sqs.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/15.207.13.23:443
2023-06-23 13:31:20.925 [] [] [SQSQueueBufferWorkerThread-16] [] [] [] [] DEBUG c.a.internal.SdkSSLSocket.close(62) - closing sqs.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/15.207.13.23:443
**2023-06-23 13:31:20.925 [] [] [SQSQueueBufferWorkerThread-16] [] [] [] [] DEBUG c.a.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleRetryableException(1227) - Unable to execute HTTP request: Read timed out Request will be retried.** **After 50 secs it got timed out and then going for next retry**

**2023-06-23 13:31:20.925 [] [] [SQSQueueBufferWorkerThread-16] [] [] [] [] DEBUG com.amazonaws.request.executeOneRequest(1288) - Retrying Request: POST https://sqs.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com /444121746292/PROD_OA_COMMUNICATION_H**
2023-06-23 13:31:20.925 [] [] [SQSQueueBufferWorkerThread-16] [] [] [] [] DEBUG c.a.http.AmazonHttpClient.doPauseBeforeRetry(1915) - Retriable error detected, will retry in 100ms, attempt number: 0
2023-06-23 13:31:21.025 [] [] [SQSQueueBufferWorkerThread-16] [] [] [] [] DEBUG c.a.auth.AWS4Signer.debug(33) - AWS4 Canonical Request: '"POST
/444121746292/PROD_OA_COMMUNICATION_H

amz-sdk-invocation-id:e7a34898-7848-0029-5fd0-a284535470da
amz-sdk-request:ttl=20230623T080211Z;attempt=2;max=4
amz-sdk-retry:1/100/495
host:sqs.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com
user-agent:aws-sdk-java/1.12.490 Linux/5.10.165-143.735.amzn2.x86_64 OpenJDK_64-Bit_Server_VM/17.0.7+7-alpine-r1 java/17.0.7 vendor/Alpine cfg/retry-mode/legacy AmazonSQSBufferedAsyncClient/1.12.490
x-amz-date:20230623T080121Z
x-amz-security-token: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

amz-sdk-invocation-id;amz-sdk-request;amz-sdk-retry;host;user-agent;x-amz-date;x-amz-security-token
fbcd61f597391a4e7e0a9eb1a917624d698d4fc3fd154d30e1b29a2242dbb9a1"
2023-06-23 13:31:21.025 [] [] [SQSQueueBufferWorkerThread-16] [] [] [] [] DEBUG c.a.auth.AWS4Signer.debug(33) - AWS4 String to Sign: '"AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
20230623T080121Z
20230623/ap-south-1/sqs/aws4_request
903819bdcc9dc60794362b8465aa30176334ba9edc58026200fb4a65554ead62"
2023-06-23 13:31:21.033 [] [] [SQSQueueBufferWorkerThread-16] [] [] [] [] DEBUG c.a.r.ClockSkewAdjuster.getServerDate(179) - Reported server date (from 'Date' header): Fri, 23 Jun 2023 08:01:21 GMT
2023-06-23 13:31:21.033 [] [] [SQSQueueBufferWorkerThread-16] [] [] [] [] DEBUG com.amazonaws.request.handle(86) - Received successful response: 200, AWS Request ID: 7ceaac46-35c2-5967-acd0-f149665367ff
2023-06-23 13:31:21.033 [] [] [SQSQueueBufferWorkerThread-16] [] [] [] [] DEBUG com.amazonaws.requestId.logHeaderRequestId(138) - x-amzn-RequestId: 7ceaac46-35c2-5967-acd0-f149665367ff
2023-06-23 13:31:21.034 [] [] [SQSQueueBufferWorkerThread-16] [] [] [] [] DEBUG c.a.s.s.MessageMD5ChecksumHandler.calculateMessageBodyMd5(196) - Message body: {"id":null,"eventCode":"otp_verify","emailId":null,"mobileNumber":"8696089862","customerId":null,"modelAttributes":{"Location":"Android","Result":"success"},"userId":8696089862,"attachments":[],"tokens":null,"commMode":null,"delayInSeconds":0,"templateId":null,"commTransactionId":null,"documents":null,"ekitRequired":null,"processedDocUrls":{},"additionalAttributes":{},"missingAttributes":null,"byPassApp":false,"async":true,"cc":null,"bcc":null,"requestId":"49b19216-8b87-4cff-bff4-1fd644c9071d"}
2023-06-23 13:31:21.034 [] [] [SQSQueueBufferWorkerThread-16] [] [] [] [] DEBUG c.a.s.s.MessageMD5ChecksumHandler.calculateMessageBodyMd5(207) - Expected  MD5 of message body: 82cb93d74c3133cc3f0057aca36fb331
```

**Tried all possible solutions to reduce this timeout of 50 secs but nothing is working.**

```
@Bean
public ClientConfiguration getClientConfig() {
        ClientConfiguration clientConfig = new ClientConfiguration();
        clientConfig = clientConfig.withSocketTimeout(7000);
        clientConfig = clientConfig.withRequestTimeout(9000);
        clientConfig = clientConfig.withConnectionTimeout(11000);
        clientConfig = clientConfig.withClientExecutionTimeout(13000);
        return clientConfig;
    }
```

```
@Bean
public SQSConnectionFactory sqsConnectionFactory() {
        String region = !StringUtils.isEmpty(sqsRegion) ? sqsRegion : AWSConfigConstants.AWS_SQS_REGION;
        //true -> refreshCredentialsAsync [credentials needs to be refreshed asynchronously]
        return new SQSConnectionFactory(new ProviderConfiguration(),AmazonSQSClientBuilder.standard()
                .withRegion(region)
                .withCredentials(InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider.createAsyncRefreshingProvider(true)));
    }
```

```
@Bean
public AmazonSQS amazonSqs() {
    String region = !StringUtils.isEmpty(sqsRegion) ? sqsRegion : AWSConfigConstants.AWS_SQS_REGION;
    return AmazonSQSClientBuilder.standard()
        .withRegion(region)
        .withClientConfiguration(getClientConfig())
        .withCredentials(InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider.createAsyncRefreshingProvider(true)).build();
}
```

How to pass CLientConfiguration so that timeout happens quickly and accordingly retry happens.

Comment: What is your queue config?

Comment: @ThomasBoudreau Does producer depends on queue configuration? 

Queue Configurations as below:- 

Maximum message size:- 256 KB

Message retention period:- 14 Days

Default visibility timeout:- 5 Minutes

Delivery delay:- 0 Seconds

Receive message wait time:- 20 Seconds